Handling Special Characters and Escape Sequences in CSV with Spark and PostgreSQL COPY Command
I am using PySpark to repartition a DataFrame and write it to a CSV file, which I later load into PostgreSQL using the COPY command. However, I am encountering the following error when executing the COPY command:
psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat: extra data after last expected column

I suspect this error is caused by special characters in my data, such as double quotes ("), commas (,), forward slashes (/), and escape characters. Here's a simplified version of my code:
df_ops.df.repartition(num_partitions).write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").option("header", "false").save(file_path)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        query = f"COPY {table_name} ({column_string}) FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER FALSE, DELIMITER ',', NULL '')"
        cursor.copy_expert(query, f)
    connection.commit()

Example Data:
Original Line:
2024-07-18 12:09:28,2012420012080452979,60,V2,"Suspected fraud, decline / Transactions declined based on Risk Score",1

After Conversion (CSV):
2024-07-18 12:09:28,2012420012080452979,60,V2,"\"Suspected fraud, decline / Transactions declined based on Risk Score\"",1

Problem:

My data contains a mix of special characters, commas, and double quotes.
The COPY command in PostgreSQL throws an error when processing the CSV due to these special characters.

Question:
How can I ensure that my CSV output from Spark is properly formatted to handle all special characters (double quotes, commas, slashes, etc.) when using the PostgreSQL COPY command? Should I adjust the Spark write options or the PostgreSQL COPY statement to handle this?
Any guidance on how to handle these escape sequences and ensure the COPY command processes the data correctly would be greatly appreciated.
Update:
I added a quote option, which resolved the issue; however, I’m concerned about potential side effects.
df_ops.df.repartition(num_partitions).write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").option("header", "false").option("quote", "\u001C").save(file_path)
query = f"COPY {table_name} ({column_string}) FROM STDIN WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER FALSE, DELIMITER ',', NULL '', QUOTE '\u001C')"



The Original Line looks fine to me, why not just use it?  2) Don't use f strings for dynamic SQL use psycopg2.sql instead.

